# `FileInputStream` going past EOF - why does it produce weird behavior instead of throwing an exception?

Tags: java, file, io, eof, fileinputstream

I made a program and purposely introduced a bug that makes the `FileInputStream` object read past the EOF character. However, that doesn't seem to make it throw any exceptions whatsoever.

- How does this object not know that it's already past the EOF symbol
  of the file?
- Why does `System.out.print()` stop printing in my terminal console after the EOF symbol has been reached? Whereas...
- `FileOutputStream` continues to indefinitely print out weird symbols to the `outagain.txt` file? What is this weird symbol? I managed to produce a text file that took up 50MB of hard disk space by the time I submitted this question.

Here is the text file `xanadu.txt` and the program producing weird behavior.

```
In Xanadu did Kubla Khan
A stately pleasure-dome decree:
Where Alph, the sacred river, ran
Through caverns measureless to man
Down to a sunless sea.
```

---

```
import java.io.*;

public class CopyBytes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
            out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt");

            while (true) {
                int ch = in.read();
                out.write(ch);
                System.out.print((char)ch);
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (in != null)
                in.close();
            if (out != null)
                out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `FileInputStream#read` do?

Comment: _Why does System.out.print() stop printing in my terminal console after the EOF symbol has been reached?_ It doesn't. It keeps printing the character associated with the integer value `-1`, which is potentially invisible on your terminal.

Comment: There is no 'EOF character'. There is an EOF *return value*, which you are ignoring. So you get it again. And again. And again. You aren't 'going past' anything here, you're just stuck in an endless loop. Your expectation that it should throw an `EOFException` is baseless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in.read()` is not documented to throw an exception when it reaches EOF.  It returns `-1`.  So you will continuously write `-1` in an infinite loop.  It's behaving as documented.

Doc: [InputStream.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--)